# ZFS send/receive fails, target has been modified, because of a zfs userspace query?

Tags: zfs, zfsonlinux

I use zfs send/receive to replicate a zfs file system to another server every day. The workflow is the standard send receive:

```
# 1. create snapshot on source
zfs snapshot ${source_fs}@${today}
# 2. send incremental update from yesterday to today to target
zfs send -i ${one_day_ago} ${source_fs}@${today} | ssh user@${target_host} "zfs receive ${target_fs}"
# 3. destroy old snapshots from two days ago on source and target
zfs destroy ${source_fs}@${two_days_ago}
ssh user@${target_host} "sudo zfs destroy ${target_fs}@${two_days_ago}"
```

This worked fine for a while. However, now I get this error from `zfs receive`:

```
cannot receive incremental stream: destination pool/filesystem has been modified since most recent snapshot
```

`zfs list -t snapshot` on the target shows a small value in the `USED` column of the most recent snapshot (something around 100K). This should be zero. The file system isn't mounted on the target.

I have a script that checks zpools and zfs quotas. The query of the current quotas (with `zfs userspace $filesystem -pH -o name,used,quota -s used`) seems to be what modifies the filesystem. Is this to be expected? I don't get why a query of some numbers modifies the filesystem.

I use Ubuntu 20.04 with OpenZFS 0.8.3 from the Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Unmounted zfs filesystems cannot be modified by anything except receive/destroy and .... (well, that's pretty much all) requests. Any zfs requests about filesystem statistics shouldn't modify the fs contents. So, concluding, I highly boubt that `zfs userspace` is modifying something (and I doubt your zfs datasets are unmounted). But if I'm wrong (about `zfs userspace`) - this is clearly a bug, and a huge one.

Comment: The filesystem really isn't mounted (the property `mountpoint` is set to `none` and `mount` doesn't list it). I also checked again and the modification doesn't happen when I comment the `zfs userspace` command and it does happen, when I run the command manually. I tried to replicate the issue with a fresh Ubuntu installation and a minimal setup, but the problem didn't occur there. So there seems to be something else that contributes to this behaviour.